# generating multiple pdf document and merge into one

Tags: codeigniter, fpdf

This is my controller function where i am running a loop to create multiple document pdf
 and merge into one.

```
public function tick_pdf(){

     $tt='';

  $name="iftekhar"; 
      $title="Event Football";
      $num=4;

    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){




    $this->pdfHeader($row->EventId);
    $this->pdf->fontpath = 'font/'; 
    //$this->pdf->AddPage();

    $this->pdf->Ln(10);


    $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $this->pdf->Cell(10);
    $this->pdf->Cell(60,10,"Name",0,0,'L');
    $this->pdf->Cell(10,10,":",0,0,'L');
    $this->pdf->MultiCell(60,10,$name,0,1);

    $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $this->pdf->Cell(10);
    $this->pdf->Cell(60,10,"Title",0,0,'L');
    $this->pdf->Cell(10,10,":",0,0,'L');
    $this->pdf->MultiCell(60,10,$title,0,1);

    $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $this->pdf->Cell(10);
    $this->pdf->Cell(60,10,"Number",0,0,'L');
    $this->pdf->Cell(10,10,":",0,0,'L');
    $this->pdf->MultiCell(60,10,$num,0,1);

    $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $this->pdf->Cell(10);
    $this->pdf->Cell(60,10,"Date",0,0,'L');
    $this->pdf->Cell(10,10,":",0,0,'L');
    $this->pdf->MultiCell(60,10,$date,0,1);



    $tt.=$this->pdf->Output('', 'S');



    }
    echo $tt;

  }
```

but I am gettiin an error in browser 
"Undefined index: data
Filename: libraries/fpdf.php
Line Number: 1659" I am using fpdf for generating pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create multiple PDF documents you will need several class instances. Actually you're working with only one instance.

Also it is not possible to concatenate a PDF document by simply concatenating their bytes ($tt .= ...). Generally it is not possible to send multiple PDF documents to the client in a single request.

If you want to create multiple pages, just remove the comment before AddPage(), delete the variable $tt and move the Output() call outside of the loop.